# Execute code when a class string or property is accesed (No Constructor)

Tags: c#

I have a project which manipulates several Databases.

What I'm looking to achieve is to have a **class** for **each database**, which will contain constant strings or properties that return its **table names** while at the same time updating a global variable holding the **Initial Catalog** for the ConnectionString. Here's an example:

```
//What the class ideally would look like
class DB1
{
    public const string Table1 = "schema.NameOfTable1"
    public const string Table2 = "schema.NameOfTable2"
}

//Usage
string table_name = DB1.Table1 //This is the code which I'd like to leave unchanged
```

So far so good, but I need to update the Initial Catalog of the cs too.

Which can be achieved using properties instead

```
class DB1
{
    public static string Table1
    {
        get
        {
            SQLClass.InitialCatalogVariable = "NameOfDB1";
            return "schema.NameOfTable1";
        }
    }
}
```

This however means that I have to implement this code for every table.

I could of course set the InitialCatalog variable in the DB1 Constructor, but then I would be forced to instantiate it like `DB1 db = new DB1(); string table_name = db.Table1` to execute the constructor code, which I'd like to avoid.

I was wondering if perhaps there's another way? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: One obvious another way is to use one of already existing ORM tools.

Comment: This doesn't seem sustainable - unless you're writing strictly single-threaded code (what is this, the 90s?), you're setting yourself up for random failures where you're connecting to the wrong database because some other thread just accessed a property elsewhere. I'd suggest using less magic.

Comment: I suppose you could use a collection/list of some sort and then create a getter and setter for all indices. Like: int this[int key] { get { } set { } }

Comment: @aguertin yes, that's an excellent idea. Making the class constructor static answered my question though, but for some reason the answerer deleted his post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a static constructor, which will be triggered whenever a static member of the class is called. Credit goes to user @InBetween, who for some reason deleted his answer

```
class DB1
{
    public static readonly string Table1 = "schema.NameOfTable1"
    public static readonly string Table2 = "schema.NameOfTable2"
    static DB1() { SQL.sInitialCatalog = "NameOfDB1"; }
}
```

`string table_name = DB1.Table1; //Retrieves table name and updates InitialCatalog`